# How to keep fillable original of pdf?

Tags: forms, pdf, signature

Signature field has been setup to mark all fields as readonly after signing a document, and usually I save a copy of this filled document to another folder not to overwrite an original. However sometimes I click Save not Save As which overwrites it. Is there any way to protect an empty original form? A pdf can't be readonly because it can't be signed.

Comment: Just mark the file as read only in the OS

Comment: it's not a solution because document can't be signed with a digital certificate.

Comment: Ok, so if you are already making a copy with Save As, why not make a copy first and use Save.

Comment: I have a folder with empty forms (originals). So every time I should first create a new folder with clients name, copy & paste original file to this folder and then fill it. Looks like going backwards. It should work, it's strange that I can't do it other way.